# Why do all Pearls Aliens speak with a female voice?

Tags: valerian-and-city-thousand-planets

I already checked IMDB cast list, and all the voice actors for Pearls Aliens are females. Even the Emperor of the Pearls Alien speaks with a female voice.

Is there any explanation behind this choice to have all female voices?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those voices aren't intended to be female. They're intended to be *ambiguously gendered* and hence alien-sounding.

> *"I met Elizabeth who I love and I think I will shoot with her
> something for sure,"* Besson told AAP in Sydney.
>
> The French director seemed impressed by Debicki's versatility as she
> took on the role of a male alien - the emperor of a compassionate
> alien race known as Pearls - in his epic space adventure set in the
> 28th Century.
>
> *"**We pitched her voice just a little bit so you don't even know if it's
> a man or a woman.** He (the character) is an emperor in fact, but she's
> a wonderful actress."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Luc Besson keen to make Debicki his star](http://www.centralnews.com.au/@breaking-news/2017/07/31/40665/luc-besson-keen-to-make-debicki-his-star)</sup></sub>

Comment: But they’re not ambiguous, they’re obviously female.

Comment: The director was clear that some of them are male, notably [the Emperor](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-FnSNtZnm-Ug/WlOctnHBeHI/AAAAAAAAElY/pz9NjAlIfTE7DwRWIlC0e9dkmEhs5jLbACEwYBhgL/s1600/valerian_mul.png) and the dudes standing behind him.

Comment: @AndyHughes They only sound female due to your Earth Human centric preconceptions as to what the female of an alien species sounds like. (and that also includes the preconception that an alien species *has* a male and a female) /s